# Instead of forwarding ports, is there a way to set up SSH on routers so I would have to login to my local network?

Tags: networking, ssh, security

Instead of forwarding ports, is there a way to set up SSH on routers so I would have to login to my local network?

I've been hacked, I think, and I'm no longer comfortable opening ports.

Is there a way to configure routers so that to gain access from the outside, I would have to SSH in?

I might be getting my terminology all wrong.

Comment: The term you are looking for is VPN, Virtual Private Network (sounds good already?). Team Viewer comes with a VPN component that is easy to use in such an environment, LogMeIn Hamachi is a dedicated one. I think the latter is not free for personal use though, like Team Viewer is. Some consumer routers also have functionality along those lines.

Comment: Even with a VPN you have to forward that port though.  I find it extremely unlikely you were actually hacked because you had an open port.

Comment: There was more to it than, that, I accidentally left unsecure real VNC on that forwarded port and google had synced my passwords. When I looked at the VNC log, their had been thousands of attempts to log on and I had a super weak password. (2 letters) because it was meant for internal only. I left the port open accidentally. I'm a moron, I know.

Comment: Does your router have a VPN server built-in? If it does then you could use this and no need to forward any ports...?

Comment: Or.. if your router supports SSH you could set it up to listen on the external interface.  There is no need for the complexity of VPN.  What kind of router do you have?

Comment: Netgear R6300 - any recommendations?